# Extract object properties from animation for each frame

Tags: python, scripting

I am an absolute beginner, please forgive me if this is a basic question. I am using Blender 2.91.

So I have n objects one in the middle and others surrounding it and the one in the middle is the parent of everything else. I am rotating the middle one using keyframes that results in the others revolving around it. Now I am playing it using python and have a handler for frame change. Here I want to extract object properties like location and position of each object for each frame.

Currently I am using obj.rotation_euler and obj.location to fetch the properties, but I get same values for all frames. (I am doing this inside the handler, so I presume it has the current frame properties in the ‘scene’ param?)

So can you please tell me how to extract these properties per frame.
Note, I need to do some mathematical calculation with the values , if that makes any difference.

Will be grateful for any help.

Edit 1 :

```
def process_obj_location(scene):    
if scene.frame_current in frame_read_counter:
    return
print(f"\nProcessing object location for frame : {str(scene.frame_current)}") 
# for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
for obj in scene.objects:
  if obj.type == 'MESH': 
      location = obj.location
      object_instance = scene_objects_dict.get(obj.name, None)
      object_instance.set_location(location)

frame_read_counter.append(scene.frame_current)
print(f"Finished processing locations for frame {str(scene.frame_current)}")


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(process_obj_location)
```

Comment: Showing your code will help us writing an answer. Basically you have to multiply (`@` operator) local coordinates by `matrix_world` property of the object.

Comment: Hi. Actually I was not sure which part of the code to post, however I have added what I think is relevant. Thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me how to use the matrix_world. It says 'NameError: name 'matrix_world' is not defined' to me. I did 'location = obj.location@matrix_world'

Comment: Finally understood what you meant :').. loc = obj.matrix_world@obj.location worked! Thank you! How can I select your answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested your code, but if everything else works, you will be fine after replacing

```
location = obj.location
```

with

```
location = obj.location @ obj.matrix_world
```

Comment: Or simply `location = ob.matrix_world.translation`